LinguistTools in Qt6.8.1
I created a project on Qt6.8.1 for multiple kits, msvc/armv8/armv7a/clangx86_64. And after build, i get a warning says as follows:
CMake Warning at C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules/FindEGL.cmake:123 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindPlatformGraphics.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "PlatformGraphics", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "PlatformGraphics"
  with any of the following names:

    PlatformGraphicsConfig.cmake
    platformgraphics-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "PlatformGraphics" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "PlatformGraphics_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "PlatformGraphics" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/FindGLESv2.cmake:13 (find_package)
  C:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicDependencyHelpers.cmake:36 (find_dependency)
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Gui/Qt6GuiDependencies.cmake:36 (_qt_internal_find_third_party_dependencies)
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Gui/Qt6GuiConfig.cmake:43 (include)
  C:/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:76 (find_package)
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtPublicDependencyHelpers.cmake:143 (find_dependency)
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Widgets/Qt6WidgetsDependencies.cmake:43 (_qt_internal_find_qt_dependencies)
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6Widgets/Qt6WidgetsConfig.cmake:43 (include)
  C:/Qt/6.8.1/android_x86_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/Qt6Config.cmake:181 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)

I don't understand this at all. What's PlatformGraphics? I'm just rewriting a msvc project into android version.It can build and run on AVD emulator. I have searched for answers, some refer this to linguistool problem. The waarning is about Cmakelist.txt as follows.
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets LinguistTools)

set(TS_FILES AddressBook_zh_CN.ts)

I tried some of them but did't work. Most importly, I want to know what's PlatformGraphicsconfig.cmake. Thanks a lot!
I have searched for answers, some refer this to linguistool problem. I tried some of them but did't work.
